# How to find the function that is computed from a recursive algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursion

The following is a recursive algorithm :

```
Procedure unknown(n belongs to N) 
  If n=0 then return 0
else return unknown (n-1)+5
```

The function that is computed from the algorithm is f(n) = 5*n. I want to know how it was computed.

Comment: The definition says $f(n) = f(n-1)+5$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(n)=f(n-1)+5,$  therefore $f(n)-f(n-1)=5\,$ is constant. So $f\,$ is affine, i.e. $f(n)=an+b.\,$ From $f(0)=0\,$ you get $b=0\,$ and from  $f(n)-f(n-1)=5\,$ you find $a=5.$

Comment: So if any function equals to a constant that makes it affine function? f(n)−f(n−1)=5 that means f(n)= an+b. In that case I can say if I have a function or a function made of other functions that equals to a constant then that makes it an affine function?

Comment: This is the discrete analogue to $f'(x)=a \Longrightarrow f(x)=ax+c$. If for a discrete function you have a constant first order difference $\Delta f(n) =f(n)-f(n-1)= a$  you have $f(n)=an+c$.